# What are the parsing rules for expressions in C?

Tags: c, parsing, expression

How can I understand the parsing of expressions like

```
a = b+++++b---c--;
```

in C?

I just made up the expression above, and yes, I can check the results using any compiler, but what I want to know is the *ground rule* that I should know to understand the parsing of such expressions in C.

Comment: @Martin: if you can get 6.2/4 removed from the C standard as "who cares", then you can close this question "who cares" ;-p Daft examples can illustrate fundamentals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a+++++b work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the standard 6.2(4):

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the
>   next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a
>   preprocessing token.

They even add the example:

> EXAMPLE 2 The program fragment x+++++y
>   is parsed as x ++ ++ + y, which
>   violates a constraint on increment
>   operators, even though the parse x ++
>   + ++ y might yield a correct expression.

So your statement:

```
a = b+++++b---c--;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a = b ++ ++ + b -- - c -- ;
```

Comment: That lexes it. Depending what the questioner means by "parse", you also need to use the operator precedence rules to construct an expression tree.

Comment: 2.1.1.2 Translation phases 7. [...] Preprocessing tokens are converted into tokens. [...] http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt

Comment: Given the lack of spaces, I assume he means parsing into tokens. There isn't a valid expression tree for his example, anyway.

Comment: "I assume he means parsing into tokens". Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

The operators involved are `++`, `--`, `+` and `-`. Some parantheses and spaces will help here:

```
a = ((b++)++) + (b--) - (c--);
```

I don't know how parsing works exactly, but there's <strike>no ambiguity involved</strike> (OK, there is, see Dingo's answer), so I guess it could be done with some simple rules like:

- One or more characters make a variable name, the most simple type of "expression"
- Operators `+` and `-` combine two "expressions"
- Operators `++` and `--` are a suffix to an "expression"

To remove the ambiguity, you can give `++` and `--` a higher priority than `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 1):

I do know know how much are you familiar with parsers, so just in case: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

If you need a formal grammar description, take a look at description for parser generator: https://javacc.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=110