# How is the expression x---y parsed? Is it a legal expression?

Tags: c++, syntax

How is the expression `x---y` parsed? Is it a legal expression?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202 (and its answers) may be of interest.

Comment: See this [Maximal Munch Principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)

Answer (score 10):

It's legal and parsed as `x--` `-` `y`.

I believe the first two minus signs are interpreted as a post-decrement operator because it's the longest token following `x` that is legal to appear. This leaves the third minus to play the role of subtraction.
This is in accordance with the **Maximal Much Rule**[1]

[1]. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch

Answer (score 1):

This is related to operator precedence. Have a look at this [table](http://cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence).

The decrement/increment operator has precedence over the arithmetic operations. It will be parsed as `x-- - y`.

**To correct my answer:** The parser matches the longest token first, so `--` is chosen over the arithmetic `-`. Resulting in the expression being parsed as `x-- - y`

Comment: +1 for mentioning operator precedence *and* linking a source.

Comment: Tokenization rules, not operator precedence.

Comment: This doesn't have to do with precedence, but with how the language is *parsed*.

Comment: The operator precedence is exactly what leads to the tokenization rules. Operator precedence just describes what the parser does with operators of any kind.

Comment: @halfdan: That is completely wrong. *Operator precedence* determines how the compiler builds expression trees out of streams of tokens. *Tokenization rules* determine how the lexer parses source code into a stream of such tokens.

Comment: `--` is chosen as the first token, because it's the longest sequence that gives a valid token. This has nothing to do with operator precedence.

Comment: The expression `---x` is tokenized as `-- - x`, even though prefix `--` has a higher precedence than unary `-`.  (This is invalid for builtin types, but may be okay for a class with weird overloaded operators.)  Token parsing is simply "greedy" and takes as many characters as possible as soon as possible.

Comment: Indeed guys. You are correct, mixed up some things in my mind. I added a comment to my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Operator precedence is a non-issue here.  For that matter, C++ doesn't have any real operator precedence, and the linked-to table is wrong in a couple of details.  (It has to be, because C++ doesn't have real operator precedence.)

Comment: It's the "maximal munch" rule being applied :) 2.4p3: "If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail."

Answer (score 1):

For all data types, it's parsed as `x-- - y`. If it's some `class` object then you have to define **post decrement** operator and **minus operator**, it will give compiler error if you just define **pre decrement** operator. That means, `x-- - y` is forced in any case.

Answer (score 0):

(x--)-y;  Which compiler do you use? What are the types of x and y?