# How does a C compiler parse code?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the operation c=a+++b mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485088/what-does-the-operation-c-ab-mean)

When it comes to four lines of C code, what would a compiler do and why?

```
  int a = 1, b = 2;
  a+++b;
  a---b;
  a++-b;
  a-++b;
```

I heard about a terminology like 'greedy compiler', could anyone explain a little further?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Entire books (quite a few of them) are written about how a compiler works -- and they're fairly large, complex books at that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Is it quite hard to find a simpler explanation?

Comment: Yes -- there are a number of steps (lexing, parsing, AST generation, etc.) involved, each of which is fairly substantial by itself.

Comment: Why on earth was this closed? Hint, the first one goes like this: `a+++b` --> `a = a++ + b`, so the expression evaluates to 3, and `a` is 2 after the evaluation is complete.

Comment: @prelic Its an exact duplicate of another question.

Comment: @Ben - Ah, I see...wouldn't it be helpful to link that for the OP?

Comment: @prelic - the link is above the question now.

Comment: hahaha, its an exact duplicate of an exact duplicate.

Comment: This question is asked at least twice per week. Maybe try the search function of this site before posting...