# postincrement in printf function

Tags: c, printf

The following code prints 7. It increments value of a, but b remains unaffected. Post increment operator is not supposed to increment first and then use the value which it has done in this case. It should be the other way around. Why this change in behaviour? Also, and perhaps more importantly, **why is b not pre-incremented**?

```
int  main() {

  int a=5, b=2;
  printf("%d", a+++b);

}
```

Comment: Something to do with `maximum munch`.. :-)

Comment: @UniCell is it? can you explain please?

Comment: Another (better?) duplicate is [What does the operation c=a+++b mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485088/what-does-the-operation-c-ab-mean)

Answer (score 1):

You have a well defined behavior. Where

```
a++ + b = 5 +2 = 7
```

If you have a pre-incrementor operator like

```
printf("%d\n",++a+b);
```

Then the output would be 8

The `++` operator has higher precendence than the `+` unary plus operator so the evaluation from left to right of

`a+++b` will happen

`a++ + b` which will fetch you 7

Post-incrementation is done by taking the value of your variable first which in this case is 5 so

`a= 5` and `b=2`

Comment: how do you know it is not `a + ++b` ?

Comment: @Ahmad because "++" is an operator too then parser must prefer "++" over "+" then it's a++ + b

Comment: @Ahmad because, compiler is _greedy_. :-)

Comment: The compiler always knows because of the rules of precedence; as people are less likely to know, if you _have_ to write something like this, do it as `(a++) + b` or `a + (++b)` so it's obvious and you're not relying on arcane rules of precedence.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `a` is added to `b` and then it is incremented

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Otherwise,  i'm pretty sure this answer will hit the low-quality review queue. :-)

Comment: gopi already have made a really good answer, i will delete mine...