# Is *pt +++= 20 valid?

Tags: c

The following was an exam question. `+++=` looked bizarre, so I asked MS Copilot and it kept saying that it's invalid, and Google Gemini said it may work but it's undefined. Is `*pt +++= 20;` valid and is guaranteed to be the same as `*pt++ += 20;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int *pt = num;
    pt++;
    *pt++ = 5;
    *pt ++= 10;
    pt--;
    *pt +++= 20;
    printf("%d %d %d %d", num[0], num[1], num[2], num[3]);
}
```

The answer of the exam was "1 5 30 4" and it was the case when I ran the code on my computer.

Comment: Basically it depends on how the compiler implements and not part of standard.

Comment: See the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485088/what-does-the-operation-c-ab-mean

Comment: @jayatubi I am not sure. gcc does not complain (but does complain when I add a certainly undefined statement, like `*pt++ = *pt++;`).

Comment: An exam question with `void main()`? Demand your tuition money back.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Funny enough, it is probably the only actual error in the program; at the same time, it is entirely irrelevant, not least because C++ did away with the useless requirement and all major compilers use the same backend for C and C++ anyway, and may only exist to give nitpickers on SO something to criticize (no offense intended ;-) ). (Oh, I see that main is actually defined void -- that's wrong in C++ as well, but still irrelevant.)

Comment: @jayatubi No! The grammar is part of the language definition, and this expression is perfectly defined.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It's not a school exam, but sort of a licence exam, whose questions are selecting the correct answer from 4 options. This question had "Error(s) occur(s)" as an option, so clearly the person who created the question tried to make us wonder "Wait, is the syntax correct?".

Comment: "MS Copilot and it kept saying that it's invalid, and Google Gemini said it may work but it's undefined" Clearly these various forms of crapware is what's invalid and undefined... don't use chat bot lie generators for learning purposes. That's an even worse idea than using Youtube or questionable internet tutorials for learning purposes.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Not sure what this means. `void main()` is a Microsoftism that every non-Microsoft compiler warns about.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI (Beating the dead horse having this discussion yet again...) `void main (void)` is the most common and preferred implementation-defined form of main used in most embedded systems. Don't stare so blindly at the hosted system sub chapter of the C standard. There's a freestanding sub chapter too...

Comment: "Error(s) occur(s)" is a correct option but not *the* correct option, because errors *may* occur but are not *guaranteed* to occur [see](https://godbolt.org/z/Tv5b5xerx). The person who created the question should know better.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It compiles cleanly for freestanding systems since gcc supports this form of main(). https://godbolt.org/z/hEM1KdGjW. Errors are kind of guaranteed to occur if a form of main() not supported by the compiler is used.

Comment: @Lundin gcc without at least `-Wall -Werror` is sort of useless.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I did compile with `-Werror` didn't I? Feel free to toss in all the strict options there are: `-Werror -Wall -std=c17 -pedantic-errors -ffreestanding`. https://godbolt.org/z/zbsdhWa9z Compiles cleanly in both gcc and clang like it ought to.

Comment: @Lundin I know all of this, my point is that an exam question should not depend on any of this, otherwise too many answers are correct for the question to be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This evil-looking (bad) exam question is actually valid and well-defined.

- `*pt = num;` point at first item, OK.
- `pt++;` point at second item, OK.
- `*pt++ = 5;` de-reference second item (and write 5 there), then point at third item, OK.
- `*pt ++= 10;` de-reference third item (and write 10 there), then point at fourth item, OK.
- `pt--;` back to third item.
- `*pt +++= 20;` de-reference third item (and add 20 there), then point at fourth item, OK.

`*pt +++= 20;` specifically is parsed according to something that's informally called "the maximal munch rule" ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work)), meaning that the C parser will look for the longest sequence that forms a valid token, then use that.

In this case `++` is a longer valid sequence than `+`, so this will always get treated like `(*pt++) +=` and not as `(*pt + ) ++=`.

Operator precedence from there: postfix `++` highest, over unary `*`, over `+=` compound assignment. The pointer increment will naturally happen at the end of the expression, like in all the other cases here. Now as it happens, the result of `*` is a so-called "lvalue", a modifiable memory location, so we can use `+=` on top of that.

Comment: (The space between `pt` and `+++` doesn't matter in this case. Had we placed a space elsewhere though, we'd overrule "maximal munch", `*pt+ ++= 20;` would have meant syntax errors.)

Comment: (Bad exam questions because whereas beginners can be expected to know of the common bad practice `*p++`, they can not be expected to know about peripheral language details such as maximal munch parsing nor the conversion of relatively complex pointer arithmetic expressions into lvalues by means of de-referencing. Far more likely this is a teacher who likes to "pose" their own C skills, rather than testing if the students picked up key knowledge... Yay, you know more about C than your students, good job...)

Comment: Just to point out that the bad practice of  `*p++` was [introduced in K&R's TCPL](https://archive.org/details/the-ansi-c-programming-language-by-brian-w.-kernighan-dennis-m.-ritchie.org/page/94/mode/2up), which had the role of a language specification in the first decade or two. I'm actually not sure whether I disagree with you -- but it sure is idiomatic and may translate directly to an addressing mode (e.g. on the PDP11's T-11), surely the reason the increment syntax exists.

Comment: Re “The pointer increment will naturally happen at the end of the expression”: The update of the operand with its incremented value is sequenced after the value computation of its operand but is not sequenced relative to other parts of the expression.