# Can you have a triple minus signs in C programming? What does it mean?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t a+++++b work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work-in-c)

I got this from page 113 on the "An Embedded Software Primer" by David Simon.

I saw this statement below:

```
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + iZoneNew ---iZoneOld;
```

Can you really have three minus signs in this line? What does a triple minus sign mean?

I believe it is a C programming statement.

Comment: You can if you know how to survive the wrath of your teammates.

Comment: to check legitimation, use a compiler, he knows more than us. to check what it does, test I/O on statments like that.

Comment: @elyashiv don't overly rely on simple test results, though. Undefined behaviour lurks at every corner.

Comment: Yet another question that deserves the "Tricky Question" badge - for baiting multiple downvoted answers.

Comment: @Mysticial, Not to mention 11 upvotes on a similar comment :p

Comment: Wait a minute, this was in a book with no explanation? Oh boy!

Comment: Sounds like yet another [bullschildt](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/bullschildt.html) book.

Comment: Interesting fact: `iZoneNew --+--iZoneOld` compiles and does what is expected. `iZoneNew -----iZoneOld` however will not compile since the compiler interprets it as `((iZoneNew--)--) - iZoneOld`.

Comment: I think this is a typing error in the book. I can't believe anybody writing books with such ugly statements.

Comment: What does it mean? It means the guy who wrote this code ought to be fired.

Comment: To be fair to the book’s author, the space after iZoneNew was added by the OP, the book just [says](http://books.google.ch/books?hl=de&id=xG2ZD55_BJAC&q=iZoneNew#v=snippet&q=iZoneNew&f=false) `iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + iZoneNew---iZoneOld;` (which isn’t much better, but at least a little bit).

Comment: This is closely related to the "approaches operator", `-->`, as used in `while (x --> 0)`.

Comment: @Joseph, I strongly suggest you click the checkmark next to your preferred answer to accept it. It's one way of saying thanks, and moves that answer to the top of the list.

Comment: @rjayavrp No, it decrements `iZoneNew` (post decrement `x--`).

Comment: My god, this gets asked about once a month, and it always gets so many upvotes.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677271 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752910 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649354 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485088

Comment: One of the most disgusting use of C I've ever seen but what can you expect from code which uses Hungarian notation?

Comment: -1. I hate these questions "what does the operator x do?" where x is '!!?++!??+&&&&+-+-+&-+&-+&+&-+-|-+-+&!&-&+-+-+&!-+|-+-!+&-+|='

Answer (score 95):

It is equivalent to:

```
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + (iZoneNew--) - iZoneOld;
```

This is in accordance with the **[maximal-munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)** principle

Comment: Finally, a completely correct answer :)

Comment: Why would anyone want to program like the original sentence? Don't you think a modified statement like this is better and clearer for the computer? iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp - iZoneOld + (iZoneNew--);

Comment: @Joseph Lee Noone would ever want to program this. However its not the computer that has trouble with it (it knows the rules if you have a proper compiler), but it is people that will constantly fail to understand this. To be honest I wouldn't even do an inline increment, like the 'readable' version, unless performance absolutely doesn't allow to make it several statements. Because even if people can read what it means, really understanding it, is different.

Comment: And yet "++++" is explicitly disallowed by syntax rules.  I believe that "--" and "++" should also have been given "no-munch" clauses in the C++ standard.  The lack of it was probably an oversight, and not a tacit condonation of this horrid coding style.

Comment: @WarrenP - "++++" is not "*explicitly disallowed by syntax rules.*" Consider [this program](http://ideone.com/EsJVZC)

Answer (score 49):

The correct answer is (as Rob said) the following:

```
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + (iZoneNew--) - iZoneOld;
```

The reason it is that way and not

```
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + iZoneNew - (--iZoneOld);
```

is a convention known as *maximum munch strategy*, which says that if there is more than one possibility for the next token, use (bite) the one that has the most characters. The possibilities in this case are `-` and `--`, `--` is obviously longer.

Comment: Why would anyone want to program like the original sentence? Don't you think a modified statement like this is better and clearer for the computer? iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp - iZoneOld + (iZoneNew--)

Comment: @JosephLee, yes it would be much better and easier to read. But the question stimulated a nice discussion about compiler strategies.

Comment: @Cthulhu, It's funny because Rob was the first to mention it, in a comment on a now-deleted answer.

Comment: @JosephLee For the computer? What about human readers?!!!!!1

Comment: Haha.. Wow, Did not know that. @chris I added the definition to his answer, to give credit where it is due. :)

Comment: I can't think of any situation where mixing -- or ++ operators with other operators in the same expression makes any sense. I can think of many situations where it confuses the reader and leads to undefined or unspecified behavior. So for the sake of the programmer themselves, as well as human readers, the proper way to fix this code is to move iZoneNew-- to a row of its own.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Draft C++11 (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) 2.5 Preprocessing tokens, clause 3 and [Draft C11 (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.4 Lexical elements, clause 4, the compiler parses the longest possible sequence of characters as the next token.

This means `---` will be parsed into the two tokens `--` and `-`, which gives

```
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + (iZoneNew--) - iZoneOld;
```

This also shows, if you're unsure about precedence or parsing rules, use parenthesis to clarify the code.

Comment: Only one of these interpretations is allowed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes There's nothing in the standard, that mandates either interpretation. So it's up to the implementation, which one it chooses.

Comment: Yes, there is. In C99 that is §6.4 Lexical elements, paragraph 4: "If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.". This is informally known as the maximal munch rule, as stated various times in comments and other answers here.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I must admit, I haven't looked into C, only C++. So, point taken.

Comment: In C++11 it is in §2.5 Preprocessing tokens, paragraph 3: "If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character: [— rules for raw string literals] [— rules for `<::`] — 
— Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a
preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail." Seems you did not look hard enough.

Comment: OMG.. -15?! Too many downvotes

Comment: @Cthulhu Don't worry, they disagreed with the initial answer. I revised it since then.

Comment: 17 down, 4 up - by my count that means @OlafDietsche is up 6 reputation on this answer.  Share and enjoy :-)

Comment: Hopefully now the the incorrect information has been edited out, some people will reverse their votes.

Comment: Cool, kudos for not giving up with so many downvotes. I just reverted mine, and gave you a +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

Equals to

`iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + (iZoneNew--) -iZoneOld;`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int iHoursTemp = 2, iZoneOld = 3, iZoneNew = 4;

//2+4 - 2 = 4
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + iZoneNew ---iZoneOld;
//2+(4--) -3 = 3   

printf("\n :%d \n", iHoursTemp);

return 0;

}
```

Gives me 3 in gcc.

Comment: Thanks. I have totally forgotten how to program in C from 10 years ago.

Comment: look at my sample code and result.

Comment: @rjayavrp, `iHoursTemp = 2 + 4 - (3 - 1);` Parentheses make the difference.

Comment: yes. correct. () is the game changer :)

Comment: This program helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score -9):

Sure why not.
This statement

```
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + iZoneNew ---iZoneOld;
```

is equivalent to

```
iHoursTemp = iHoursTemp + iZoneNew -(--iZoneOld); //first decrement iZoneOld then perform rest of the arithmetic operation.
```

A little brain teaser, but fun to write :-)

Comment: Nope, that is the incorrect interpretation of that statement.