# What is &&& operation in C

Tags: c++, c, operators, compiler-optimization, gcc-warning

```
#include <stdio.h>

volatile int i;

int main()
{
    int c;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
         c = i &&& i;
         printf("%d\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program compiled using `gcc` is

```
0
1
1
```

With the `-Wall` or `-Waddress` option, `gcc` issues a warning:

```
warning: the address of ‘i’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
```

How is `c` being evaluated in the above program?

Comment: I believe it's `i && (&i)`? Interesting that I can't find a duplicate post on SO.

Comment: Left-to-right (except where otherwise specified, which would only be `=`), so `&&` then `&i`

Comment: Why do you answer in comments rather than answering the question itself?

Comment: `while (i &&& i <-- j) {}`.

Comment: @KennyTM: I didn't quite understand `while (i &&& i <-- j) {}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you have a triple minus signs in C programming? What does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874179/can-you-have-a-triple-minus-signs-in-c-programming-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but s a similar question and that's a good link

Comment: @Manav http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator?rq=1

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Maximum munch, it is the same answer, for `&&&`, `+++`, `---`, etc, is it not?

Comment: @Cthulhu well I'm sure there are better fits than `---`, no?

Comment: its the same classic maximal munch rule, all over again as @Cthulhu already mentioned. Bear in mind that this question is again a dulpicate, I have also found this once already, but wasn't marked as duplicate.

Comment: You tagged the question "gcc-warning", but you didn't show the gcc warning (I've added it). You also tagged it "linux", which is irrelevant (I've removed the tag).

Comment: GCC accepts **`&&&&`**: `int main(){j:return 0&&&&j;}`

Comment: @nneonneo , Whoa. Could you split that up? What does it do?

Comment: 0 && (&&j). It uses a GCC extension to take the address of label j, which should always evaluate to a non-zero value.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

It's `c = i && (&i);`, with the second part being redundant, since `&i` will never evaluate to `false`.

For a user-defined type, where you can actually overload unary `operator &`, it might be different, but it's still a **very bad idea**.

If you **turn on warnings**, you'll get something like:

> warning: the address of ‘i’ will always evaluate as ‘true’

Comment: Why not : `c = i & (&&i);`; Where `i` is some label?

Comment: @anishsane `i` is defined as `int` and there's no labels in the question. Also, maximal munch...

Comment: @anishsane: And the `&&` operator to take the address of a label is non-standard gcc extension anyway. But even if it were standard, the maximal munch rule would prevent it from being parsed that way (unless you insert a space).

Comment: Actually, `&i` can evaluate to `false`.  Its used sometimes for defaults.  Example: `void fn(type& x = *reinterpret_cast<type*>(NULL));`  What is the value of `&x` in `fn` if `fn` is called without parameters?  It's 0 a.k.a. false.  However, using it the way described, it'll always be true unless `i == 0`, and if one was using it as I described, it would be `c = &i && i`.

Comment: @Adrian you can't dereference a null pointer, which is what the `*` before `reinterpret_cast<type*>(NULL)` does.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Although the type is dereferenced, it's not an error till the value is accessed.  That's my understanding.  Is it defined otherwise in the standard?

Comment: @Adrian there's no value to speak of. Dereferencing a NULL pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30599/discussion-between-adrian-and-luchian-grigore)

Comment: I stand corrected. void fn(type& x = *reinterpret_cast<type*>(NULL)); is invalid.

Comment: There is a misconception: UB != invalid. UB means "the language spec. don't define it", but compiler implementer can. And there are compilers that allow `int& a = *(int*)0;` and exhibit exactly that behavior (`&a == nullptr`). Of course code like that is not portable (is in fact compiler specific), but the assertion "&i is always true" is not correct: being UB, it *may* be false. No-one grants it, but it can be.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia any statements about the behaviour of a code snippet should be assumed to have "(unless there is already UB in which case anything could happen)" implied.

Answer (score 120):

There is no `&&&` operator or token in C.  But the `&&` (logical "and") and `&` (unary address-of or bitwise "and") operators do exist.

By the [maximal munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) rule, this:

```
c = i &&& i;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
c = i && & i;
```

It sets `c` to 1 if both `i` and `&i` are true, and to 0 if either of them is false.

For an int, any non-zero value is true. For a pointer, any non-null value is true (and the address of an object is always non-null). So:

It sets `c` to 1 if `i` is non-zero, or to `0` if `i` is equal to zero.

Which implies that the `&&&` is being used here just for deliberate obfuscation. The assignment might as well be any of the following:

```
c = i && 1;
c = !!i;
c = (bool)i;          // C++ or C with <stdbool.h>
c = i ? 1 : 0;        /* C */
c = i ? true : false; // C++
```