# Why is `&` used for both binary AND and address-of in C?

Tags: c, syntax

This question is in response to [What is &&& operation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13946938/713554) which got me thinking about `&` being used both as binary AND and address-of.

Why is the same symbol used for both these very dissimilar tasks? When thinking about it, `@` would seem to be a better symbol for address-of.

I don't expect it to cause much problem in practice since the compiler will probably catch most faulty use, but it would probably be possible to create code involving macros that looks like it is doing a binary AND while it is actually doing address-of.

Comment: I've always wondered this. Pascal uses `@` which seems much more intuitive to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `@` was not used for "address of" (as you suggested would be a good choice) is that that character was not part of the [ISO 646 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646), which was actually used back in the early days of C.

While it is true that the designers of C *could have* used `@` and designed a trigraph sequence for it, I suspect they felt it was not really worth the hassle.  The fact that `&&&` *can* appear in people's code was probably not considered reason enough to choose a different operator symbol.

Comment: Agreed, the only reason for any ambiguity for humans is people *trying* to be clever by omitting whitespace and using obscure language features, rather than actually *being* clever...

Comment: +1: I expected there to be some historical reason. A more limited character set explains why the same characters are used for multiple meanings. It was not `&&&` I had in mind when questioning why `&` has multiple uses though. More something like `a & b` where `a` ends up being set by `#define a`. This looks like a `AND` but is in fact not. Hopefully the compiler can spot the mistake, but that depends entirely on what you use the result for.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is any big reason why it's used for 2 different things.

Luckily, there is no ambiguity in the language because one use is a unary operator and the other one is a binary operator (i.e. has two operands). Ditto for * (multiplication or dereference).

Comment: It is also used for bit-wise AND. So it can also be a binary operator.

Comment: ^^ By binary AND , he meant same as bitwise AND. && is called logical and.