# decrement operator vs subtraction operator

Tags: subtraction, decrement

If I write a code like(in c)

```
    x=1;
    z=2;
    y=x---z;
```

will first two - be treated as post-decrement and later one as subtraction

or first - will be treated as subtraction and other two as pre-decrement

and what if I put a space to make it the other (because in  c program doesn't change by white space)

Comment: Also more specific duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874179/can-you-have-a-triple-minus-signs-in-c-programming-what-does-it-mean).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §6.4 , *lexical elements*,  <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the
>   next preprocessing token is the **longest sequence of characters that could constitute a
>   preprocessing token**. [..]

So,

```
y=x---z;
```

is

```
y= (x--) - z;
```

This is also called as [Maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) rule.

Comment: but I have always thought that white space has no meaning in c

Comment: @DhruvaMehrotra unless they are used as separator(s), just as here...