# Is sum+++i undefined behavior in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I tested this on different machine and on different compiler, but I gave out the same output:

```
int sum = 10, i = 5;
printf("%d", sum+++i);
```

Is this well-defined or undefined behavior in C?

Comment: Please search for "maximum munch" on Stack Overflow, and you'll find plenty of duplicates.

Comment: @KerrekSB It _was_ closed for the right reason. It got 1 confused duplicate vote by someone else, then dupe hammer by yours sincerely. Maybe this is a site design mistake, it should only show the duplicate which gets most votes.

Comment: Related to [Why doesn't a+++++b work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/1708801)

Comment: @george-stocker I think that duplicte is a pretty poor question, it is basically a confusion over how post-increment works which by today's standards is off-topic and I would personally close it as such. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5649354/1708801) is actually much closer and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/1708801) is also not a bad more general fit either, I would choose to close it as both if that is possible.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks; fixed. I'm not a C++ expert, so my goal was to set things to how they were. It was confusing to follow all the threads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's well defined. `sum+++i` is parsed as `sum++ + i`, which results as `15` (with the side effect of incrementing `sum`).

> #### C11 §6.4 Lexical elements
>
> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the
>   next preprocessing token is the **longest** sequence of characters that could constitute a
>   preprocessing token. There is one exception to this rule: header name preprocessing tokens are recognized only within `#include` preprocessing directives and in implementation-defined locations within `#pragma` directives. In such contexts, a sequence of characters that could be either a header name or a string literal is recognized as the former.

And a similar example is followed:

> EXAMPLE 2 The program fragment `x+++++y` is parsed as `x ++ ++ + y`, which violates a constraint on increment operators, even though the parse `x ++ + ++ y` might yield a correct expression.

Comment: May I know where you got this information? (+1 TOP answer :D)

Comment: @YuHao: The point is, this program is well-defined even if you never compile it. Even if you wrote it on paper on a lonely island, it would be well formed C with predictable semantics. Why rob us of this insight?

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point. I'll edit the post not to blame the compiler :)

Comment: @Rizier123 It's quoted from the C standard. You might be interested in [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
printf("%d", sum+++i);
```

corresponds to

```
printf("%d", sum++ + i);
```

and is a well-formed statement. There is no any undefined behaviour.

The output will be

```
15
```

According to the C Standard (6.4 Lexical elements)

> 4 If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to
>   a given character, the next preprocessing token is **the longest
>   sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token**.

Comment: can you please add a line about why the interpretation will not be as `printf("%d", sum + ++i);`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Because `LTR` and because NOT `RTL`

Comment: @SouravGhosh as a special hint: read the answer from Yu Hao, it's very well explained