# Why doesn't c = a+++++b work in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please help me understanding the error a+++++b in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/please-help-me-understanding-the-error-ab-in-c)

In a discussion today the topic of pre/post increment came up.

We tried several combinations of addition and increment:

```
c = a+++b //works
c = a++ + ++b //works
c = a+++ ++b //works
c = a+++++b // doesn't work, compiler error "error: invalid lvalue in increment
```

Where is the difference? What exactly does that additional whitespace add for the parser so the program compiles?

Comment: Exact duplicate, but SO search does not seem to work well for finding questions containing "+++++"...

Comment: @Mehrhad: which I then could close as duplicate to this one ;)