# How will C parse this sentence?

Tags: c, puzzle

According to the official description of the C language, what number will be returned?

```
int a, b;
a = 5;
b = a+++++a;
return b;
```

Comment: @Tom: Actually, everyone with a bit of knowledge about lexical analysis (nothing C specific needed here) can tell you how it's parsed, and everyone who reads SO regularily should have seen explanations that it's undefined behaviour once a month.

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question already - finding them is difficult though because it seems you can't search for "+++++" or "a+++++a".

Comment: @delnan: Make that once a week or more. Some times of the year it becomes daily...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't c = a+++++b work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677271/why-doesnt-c-ab-work-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is parsed as:

```
b = (a++)++ + a;
```

This is an invalid expression. The increment operator can't be applied twice as `(a++)` isn't an lvalue.

The tokenizer isn't context-aware and will match the longest token possible, so it is not parsed as the syntactically valid `a++ + ++a`. (That still would be invalid code, though, since it modifies `a` twice without a sequence point which invokes undefined behavior.)

Comment: Why would a++ + ++a be invalid? Couldn't it evaluate left-to-right like: (5) + (6)

Comment: By invalid code @John means that it invokes undefined behaviour. So it would compile, we just don't know what it would do.

Comment: @VolatileStorm: "undefined behavior" could mean "not compile".

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that before. It's undefined compiler behaviour, which could lead to undefined run-time behaviour, right? But obviously it doesn't have to lead to any run-time behaviour if it doesn't compile! I'd always just thought of it as run-time behaviour :).

Comment: @Robert Martin: It's invalid because the language standard explicitly calls it out as undefined behavior (6.5, para 2); an object may not have its value modified more than once by the evaluation of an expression between any two sequence points.  Secondly, the order of evaluation for arithmetic expressions is unspecified; the compiler doesn't have to evaluate it left-to-right.

Comment: @Dietrich: The compiler is required to accept a program containing `a++ + ++a` because it won't necessarily be executed. For a worst-case example, consider `if (problem_that_is_not_known_to_halt()) `a++ + ++a`; which only invokes UB when a new result in CS is proved. :-)

Comment: @R..: I said "could mean", but that doesn't mean it wouldn't compile in all cases.  For example, a complier *could* reject `int main() { int i = 4; return i++ + ++i; }`