# Why "a+++++b" can not be compiled in gcc, but "a+++b", "a++ + ++b", and "a+++ ++b" can be?

Tags: c, gcc, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please help me understanding the error a+++++b in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/please-help-me-understanding-the-error-ab-in-c)

Here is is the sample code, why "a+++++b" can not be compiled , but others can be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    c = a+++b;
    printf("a+++b is: %d\n", c);

    c = a = b = 0;
    c = a++ + ++b;
    printf("a++ + ++b is: %d\n", c);

    c = b = a = 0;
    c = a+++ ++b;
    printf("a+++ ++b is: %d\n", c);

    c = b = a = 0;
    c = a+++++b;      // NOTE: Can not be compiled here.
    printf("a+++++b is: %d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why doesn't a+++++b work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/995714)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `a+++++b` is parsed as `a ++ ++ + b` and not as `a ++ + ++ b`[C's tokenizer is greedy]. `a++` returns an rvalue and you cannot apply `++` on an rvalue so you get that error.

```
a+++b; // parsed as a ++ + b
a+++ ++b; // parsed as a ++ + ++ b
```

Read about Maximal Munch Rule.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is greedy so your expression

```
a+++++b
```

will be understood as

```
a++ ++ +b
```

Answer (score 5):

The `+` operators cascade ... with `a+++++b`, there is no l-value (memory addressable value) to add against after the addition operations are cascaded.

Put another way, `a+++b` is the same as `(a++) + b`.  That's a valid operation. The same is true with `a+++ ++b` which equates to `(a++) + (++b)`.  But with `a+++++b`, you don't get that via the C-parser.  To the parser it looks like `((a++)++) + b`, and since (a++) returns a temp, that's not an l-value that can be incremented again via the `++` operator.

Answer (score -2):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int a = 0;
 int b = 0;
 int c = 0;
 c = a+++b;
 printf("a+++b is: %d\n", c);

 c = a = b = 0;
 c = (a++)+(++b);
 printf("a++ + ++b is: %d\n", c);

 c = b = a = 0;
 c = (a++)+(++b);
 printf("a+++ ++b is: %d\n", c);

 c = b = a = 0;
 c = (a++)+(++b);     
 printf("a+++++b is: %d\n", c);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP (presumably) already knows that this would work; they wanted to know *why* `a+++++b` does not. Also, bad formatting. (Not the one who downvoted btw, just making a educated guess at why they did.)