# Java Multiple Consecutive Operators

Tags: java, operators

(**Note**: I came across this somewhat accidentally, so it may not be practical, but I am just very curious)

I wanted to print out a value, which was the sum of two values, after incrementing the second. Something like so:

```
int first = 10;
int second = 20;
System.out.println(first + ++second);  //31
System.out.println(first);             //10
System.out.println(second);            //21
```

Maybe not the neatest code, but it worked. But then, I started experimenting.

```
System.out.println(first +++ second);  //30
System.out.println(first);             //11
System.out.println(second);            //21
```

That's fine; it means that the first was incremented after being added, and that whitespace can be ignored here. Cool. But then...

```
System.out.println(first +++++ second);  //"Invalid Argument", doesn't work
```

While

```
System.out.println(first ++ + ++ second);  //31
System.out.println(first);             //11
System.out.println(second);            //21
```

Works fine, but for some reason, is still different than

```
System.out.println(first + + + ++ second);  //31
System.out.println(first);             //10
System.out.println(second);            //21
```

And maybe the strangest of all,

```
System.out.println(first + + + + + + second);  //30
System.out.println(first);             //10
System.out.println(second);            //20
```

So what's going on here? When is whitespace between operators ignored, and when is it not? Why can I write "+ + + + +", without any issues?

Thanks!

Comment: If you keep doing weird things, all your friends will hate you :(

Comment: Favor simplicity over curiosity...

Comment: `+` `++` are **three** different operators. addition, pre-increment, post-increment.

Comment: @Styl Ugh, no! Curiosity is a _fantastic_ quality in a good programmer. I think it's great to say "I would never do this in real code, but still I'm curious as to what's going on."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This comes down to [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). The order of operations goes:

- postfix (`foo++`, `foo--`)
- unary (`++foo`, `--foo`,  `+expr`, ...)
- ...
- additive (`+`, `-`)
- ...

So, let's take a look at each expression:

`first + ++second` is `first + (++second)`. That's fine.

`first +++ second` is `(first++) + second`, which works as you said it does.

`first +++++ second` is `((first ++)++)+ second)`, but `(first ++)` is a value (not a variable) and thus can't be incremented -- that's what the error is trying to tell you.

`first ++ + ++ second` explicitly tells Java to split things up differently than above: it becomes `(first ++) + (++ second)`, which is fine.

`first + + + + + + second` becomes `first + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ second)))))`. The unary `+` just means "not negated", so `+foo == foo`. Therefore this expression simplifies to `first + second`, which is obviously fine.

Comment: Ooh, a positive unary operator. Didn't know that existed. And everything else makes sense. Cheers!

Comment: So why is `second` incremented by 2 if the last expression evaluates to `first + second`? The OP states that `second` is equal to 22 after the last expression.

Comment: @bcsb1001 OP must have written the wrong output in the comment -- it doesn't increment as part of this expression. See https://gist.github.com/yshavit/c6a347b850bbc026e508

Comment: Ya, woops, my bad, I'll fix that for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to close it as a duplicate since it's a different language but I believe it to be the same reason as layed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752910/why-ab-can-not-be-compiled-in-gcc-but-ab-a-b-and-a/5752941#5752941).

It's simply a matter of parsing and these bullets should help you figure it out:

- Java allows for *a lot* of whitespace
- Consecutive mathematical operators like `+` bear no extra meaning and only one will be applied
- Parsing is done from left to right

Code: `first +++ second`
Parsed: `first++ + second`

Code: `first +++++ second`
Parsed: There is no binary operator `++` since it will try to make `++ ++ +`

Code: `first ++ + ++ second`
Parsed: `first++ + ++second`

Code: `first + + + ++ second`
Parsed: `first + ++second`

Code: `first + + + + + + second`
Parsed: `first + second`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I searched for multiple consecutive operators, but not for "+++++".

Comment: I agree this to be a duplicate, but this was very interesting to come across. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 0):

I think the parser is greedy, i.e. it always eats as many plus-signs as available, for reducing them to the increment operator if possible.

I.e. it goes from left to right and when it spots two subsequent plus-signs, it evaluates them as increment operator, while a single plus sign followed by a non-plus-symbol is evaulated as a binary plus or as unary plus, depending on the left side operand.