# How to handle arrays of arrays defined by a class

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a template Array class. I can use it to declare things like this,

```
Array<int> oneDimenional(5);
```

But not this...

```
Array<Array<Array<Array<Array<Array<Array< int >>>>>>> Craziness(1000);
```

My class starts out like this,

```
template <typename T>

class Array{

private:
    int len;
    T *arr;
public:
    Array() {
        int len = 0;
    }
    Array(int size) {
        arr = new T[size];
        len = size;
    }
    ~Array() {
        delete[] arr;
    }
//...
};
```

I'm guessing I need to change my constructor?

Comment: One problem I can see is that in your constructor you do `int len = 0;` instead of `len = 0;`, i.e. you declare a new, local variable rather than setting the value of the member `len`. The compiler might issue a warning about that.

Comment: (Of course it would be even much better to use an initialization list: `Array() : len(0),arr(0) { }`.)

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. I get the impression that the question is how to pass all of the different dimensions to the internal types... if that is the case, you should also add what version of the standard you want to use, as it is simpl-ish in C++11 and much harder to do in C++03

Comment: Fixed! Thank you. Now I see my error is _actually_ with my copy constructor being used. (code not shown because I assumed the wrong error)

Answer (score 2):

```
Array<Array<int> > arr(10);
```

leave space between >>.
since this is considered as >> right shift. and thats why the error
It 'll be shown in compiler itself and its a common mistake.

```
 error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list
```

so your code should be

```
Array<Array<Array<Array<Array<Array<Array< int > > > > > > > Craziness(1000);
```

Comment: True, although it may be worth noting that this problem exists in C++98/03, but not in C++11.

Comment: @jogojapan could you please explain how? even i'm a beginner. [c++11 is new to me]

Comment: Oh, it's just that in C++11 the rules were changed. So you can write `Array<Array<int>>` without spaces and it will work. See this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785496/c-templates-angle-brackets-pitfall-what-is-the-c11-fix. But you are right nevertheless that this is likely the problem the OP faced. +1.

Comment: This is correct! I now see my driver program is actually doing that, Array< Array<int> > b(3); (no ill-typed craziness) but I now see my error may actually be with a different piece of code which uses the copy constructor.