# How do I create a QList of QList<QString>?

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-10, qt5

How can I make a QList of QList?

This:

`QList<QList<QString>> output;`

Results:

> error: template argument 1 is invalid
>        QList output;

**UPDATE**

My Qt version:

[image]

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I'll edit the error, sorry.

Comment: @eyllanesc added.

Comment: I find it strange, in Qt 5.11 I do not see that problem: https://imgur.com/a/2AKkgKZ, 
Although it would be more readable to use: `QList<QStringList> output;`

Comment: The line is working just fine in the tags you've added. Please provide a minimal working example to regenerate the problem. More info is needed such as the compiler, the pro. file, and the cpp file.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.5.0... maybe Support for this was added later?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a high version because QWebView doesn't work well on high versions. Any workaround?

Comment: it's not a issue with 5.5. Try adding a space between angle brackets: `QList<QList<QString> >`. And also make sure you have all necessary includes `#include <QList>` and `#include <QString>`

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov it worked adding the spaces oO why?

Comment: @Jack Some old compilers think that the `>>` part of `QList<QList<QString>>` is the `operator>>`. Adding the space tells the compiler that that's not the case.

Comment: you compile with old c++ standart, this issue was fixed in c++11 see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785496/c-templates-angle-brackets-pitfall-what-is-the-c11-fix) question

Comment: In particular this happens before C++11 on compilers that conform to the standard; even then many compilers added support for figuring out when you did this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template within template: why "\`>>' should be \`> >' within a nested template argument list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695261/template-within-template-why-should-be-within-a-nested-template-arg)

Comment: @Jack Also, have you considered using [Qt WebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtwebengine-index.html) instead of QWebView? QWebView is deprecated and Qt WebEngine is supposed to be used instead, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html. Qt WebEngine works well with the latest version of Qt.

Comment: Even though the problem has been found to be the use of C++11 closing right angled brackets, it's still very peculiar you get this error because you're using MSVC 2013 for the compiler and [even MSVC 2010 had support for this C++11 feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#Anchor_0). Weird.