# Auto formatter changes > > to >>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

I'm having a problem with the C++ extension of VScode. Whenever I define a matrix consisting of vectors like `vector<vector<int> >` and use the auto formatter, it changes the code to `vector<vector<int>>` which results in a compiler error.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: That sounds like you are using a really old compiler version where that parsing issue is not resolved by the language yet... Is upgrading to a newer compiler an option?

Comment: You'd be hard-pressed to find a compiler that doesn't support this in C++11 mode. @Erebos Try adding `-std=c++11` to the compiler flags.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The VSCode C++ extension uses clang-format for formatting the document. If you are stuck with an old compiler which doesn't support C++11, just add a **.clang-format** file in your workspace with following line:

```
Standard : Cpp03
```

For more formatting options, refer to the following link:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 28):

The compiler error is that `>>` is interpreted as the right shift operator instead of two consecutive template argument list delimiters. Before C++11 this was how the language required the parser to work. However, in C++11, an exception was added to prevent this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785496/c-templates-angle-brackets-pitfall-what-is-the-c11-fix) for more information.

The best solution would be to upgrade your compiler to C++11 or later.