# Is "a+++i" equal to "(a++)+i"

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 1, i = 3, x, y, z;
    a = 1; i = 3;
    x = a+++i;
    a = 1; i = 3;
    y = a++ + i;
    a = 1; i = 3;
    z = a + ++i;
    printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);
    scanf(" ");
    return 0;
}
```

This code output appears to be `4 4 5`. But why is `a+++i` equals to `a++ + i`?

Is it because compilers always read source code from left to right?

Or is it because the operation follows [the order of precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)?

And will it work the same on all compilers?

Comment: Related to [Why doesn't a+++++b work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/1708801)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C11 standard, part `6.4 (Lexical elements)/4` says (and in C99 it's the same):

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the
>   next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a
>   preprocessing token.

There is also an example there:

> The program fragment `x+++++y` is parsed as `x ++ ++ + y`, which violates a constraint on
>   increment operators, even though the parse `x ++ + ++ y` might yield a correct expression.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say all, since C compiler implementation may be different. But generally yes, you are right. A C compiler is supposed to be greedy, i.e. read as much as possible, so `+++` == `++ +`.

Comment: Aren't templates found in C++?