# make the meaning of /* for dereference and dividing not for commenting by adding some special character

Tags: c++, c

I have a code like this:

```
int quotient = 100/*ptr;
```

where ptr is a pointer to interger.

But it's taking `/*` as the comment.
How can I make the meaning of divide by pointer dereference value? What extra special character I have to put to have this meaning?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP should know better and just put spaces around binary arithmetic operators.

Comment: if putting a space between the '/' and the '*' does not work, then put parens around the divisor, like so: 'int quotient = 100/(*ptr);'

Comment: I think off-topic tag is improper. But I am OK with something like,OP hasn't done enough research or so:)

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't be off-topic, because while it is technically a typographical error, *it is very likely to help future readers.*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This happens because language tried to reuse the tokens. (`*` in this case)

Solution is to put a space between `/` and `*` to beat maximal munch.

```
int quotient = 100 / *ptr;
```

Another way is to add a parenthesis or use another local variable:

```
int quotient = 100/(*ptr);
```

Answer (score 25):

First, you can replace `*ptr` with `ptr[0]`, as both have the same semantics:

```
int quotient = 100/ptr[0];
```

And since array indexing is commutative, you can swap the operands:

```
int quotient = 100/0[ptr];
```

To the casual reader, this may look like division by zero, but of course `[]` has higher precedence than `/`.
You may want to put a space there, just in case:

```
int quotient = 100/0 [ptr];
```

Congratulations, you now have a job for life!

Comment: `[` and `]` may be difficult to maintain for some people, so I suggest using `<:` and `:>` instead.

Comment: @righrfold why not replace the latter one with `??)` so you have `int quotient = 100/0 <: ptr??)`. so even C programmers can read it.

Answer (score 13):

Change it to this:

```
int quotient = 100/(*ptr);
```

or

```
int quotient = 100/ *ptr;
```

`/*` *together* is used for multi-line comments in almost all languages I know until now.

Comment: That cannot be many languages then :) And the OP is already aware it is the "comment" sequence.

Answer (score 13):

C and C++ use [maximal munch rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) to parse the tokens. The *longest valid match string* after a token will be the next token.

Therefore in `int quotient = 100/*ptr;`, `/*` will be a single token instead of two tokens `/` and `*`. This is an undesirable effect of the rule.

> In some situations, "maximal munch" leads to undesirable or unintuitive outcomes. For instance, in the C programming language, the statement `x=y/*z;` (without any whitespace) will probably lead to a syntax error, since the `/*` character sequence initiates a (unintended) comment that is either unterminated or terminated by the end token `*/` of some later, unrelated actual comment (comments in C do not nest). What was actually meant in the statement was to assign to the variable x the result of dividing the value in y by the value obtained by dereferencing pointer z; this would be perfectly valid (though not very common) code. It can be stated by making use of whitespace, or using `x=y/(*z);`.
>
> <sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch#Drawbacks</sup>

To fix this you just need to add a space, new line or another dummy token (like a comment) to separate `/` and `*`. You can also surround the expression by brackets like in the other answer

```
int quotient = 100/ /* this will work */ *ptr;
int quotient = 100/
    *ptr; // this will also work
```

A similar question: [Why doesn't `a+++++b` work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/995714)

Comment: `int quotient = 100//* this works in C89 but not in C++ and C99+ */*ptr;`

Comment: @DonaldDuck did you read my answer? `To fix this you just need to add a space, new line or another dummy token (like a comment) to separate / and *`