# How are bunched together operators in c++ separated

Tags: c++

In C++,

```
is 
(a+++b)
processed as 
((a++) + b) 
or 
(a + (++b))
```

Where is this clarified in the standard?

---

the first part of this question has many answers, but the specific question WHERE IN THE STANDARD IS THIS CLARIFIED is not answered very clearly elsewhere.

for those interested, it is at 2.4.3 in the 2003 C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882)

*"If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing
token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that would
cause further lexical analysis to fail."*

Comment: Why write such code that is difficult to understand

Comment: I wouldn't, but someone might.

Comment: I have this great rule to writing C++: don't write weird things. This would be an example of a weird thing. If you can't immediately tell by looking at it what's happening then simply don't do it and resort to simpler and more straightforward ways, it avoids making mistakes like these.

Comment: @samgak, Java is not C++ and could have totally different rules for expressions like these.

Comment: writing a parser and it interested me

Comment: The C++ standard almost takes this identically even the examples from the [C standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24947922/1708801)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `a++ +b`, because the tokenizer is greedy and will try to match `++` wherever possible.