# C programming unary operator precedence

Tags: c++, c

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
    {
     int c=10,b;
     b=++c+++c;
     printf("%d",b);
     return 0;
    }
```

Could someone please let me know,why it is throwing compilation error?

Comment: Ever heard of spaces?

Comment: This code has a lot of problems but the issue you seem to want to know about is the [maximal munch rule](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/1708801)

Comment: -1: are you compiling in C or C++?  They are different languages.  -1: What is the compilation error?  Saying there is an error is less useful than saying the error.  -1: Asking about `+++` as a general rule without sufficient research effort shown.  +1: actual reproducible example.  Verdict: -2.  Feel free to improve your question and @Yakk me and I'll change my vote.

Answer (score 3):

The gibberish is tokenised as

```
++ c ++ + c
```

and parsed as

```
((++c)++) + c
```

This tries to increment the *rvalue* yielded by `++c`, which isn't allowed. You can only increment an *lvalue* (or a class type, in C++).

Even if it were allowed, this would give undefined behaviour: you'd have an unsequenced modification and use of the value of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error would be solved if you put a space in `++c + ++c`

```
b = ++c + ++c;
```

But that just fixes the compilation error. What you are doing is Undefined Behavior. Trying to change the value of `c` more than once in the same expression using `++` will lead to undefined Behavior.

Read [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Except this is undefined behaviour. For example, I get 23 with Clang and 24 with GCC when compiling as C++, along with a warning by both.

Comment: @chris , Yes, it is Undefined Behavior. Never said it wasn't.