# A C++ program. Why does this code work?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  int a=1;
  int b=2;
  int c=a+++b;
  cout<<"c"<<c<<endl;
}
```

c's value turns out to be **3**. While, it gives me an **error for c=a++b**. What is happening here? Why does **c=a+++b** work?

Comment: It is parsed as `a++ + b` which is an increment and an addition.

Comment: @chris You are probably right.

Comment: Although C, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work-in-c) is a similar concept. One key phrase relating to this is *maximal munch*. That is, `a+++b` is `a++ + b`, not `a + ++b`.

Answer (score 2):

A key part of why `a+++b` "works", and `a++b` doesn't is the way the C and C++ language parsing is defined. It is what is called a 'greedy' parser. It will combine as many elements as possible to produce a valid token.

So, given that it's a greedy parser, `a++b` becomes `a++ b`, which is not valid. `a+++b` becomes `a++ + b`, which is syntactically valid - whether that is what you WANT is another matter. If you want to write `a + +b`, then you need spaces to separate the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like *a* is post increment then added to *b* with bad spacing. For example a++ + b. The variable *a* is evaluated then incremented. That being said a++b is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

(++) post-increment has the highest precedence, sou you end up with `(a++) + b`.