# C - Precedence increment/decrement?

Tags: c, increment, decrement

I just started learning C Programming and I have a question based on expression evaluation.
If we have 3 variables, `a`,`b`, and `c`:

1. `c=a+++b++;`
2. `c=a+++++b;`

Why is the 1st expression valid and 2nd invalid?

Comment: The answer is colloquially known as the 'maximal munch' rule.  The lexical analyzer will grab as much as it can to make a token.  When it sees `c = a+++b++;`, it recognizes `a++ + b++`.  When it sees `c = a+++++b;`, it recognizes `a++ ++ +b` and you can't increment the result of an increment operation.  There must be other questions asking the same.

Comment: Adding to what Jonathan stated, that is the reason the compiler shall prompt you with *lvalue required for increment operator.*

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This may be a better duplicate (you beat me by 36 seconds): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work-in-c

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: hmmm — that's a good one for the second half; what I gave is a good one for the first half.  Either could be acceptable; list both is good.  The one disadvantage of Mjölnir is that it doesn't allow you to accumulate alternative duplicates unless someone has already nominated something else.

Comment: A better question is: why would anyone ever write something like `c=a+++++b;`. If you are a beginner, don't ponder about writing wildly obscure code. It is counter-productive and will make you worse at programming, not better.

Comment: That being said, simply fix the expression by adding some minus symbols: `c = a+++-+-++b;`. Now spend some hours pondering why that one will compile, please.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Added your suggestion using the new [Gold badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) feature.  It seems to work!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Awesome! That's a very nice feature to finally have.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the C compiler does interpret `a+++` as `a++ +`, while `+++b` generates an error even if you put another variable before it.

In practice it is a very bad idea to write such expressions without spaces. You would confuse yourself when you come back to look at your code, and annoy anyone else looking at it :) Just rewrite:

1. `a++ + b++`
2. `a++ + ++b`

and everything will work as expected.

Comment: "In principle both 1) and 2) should have worked" - not in C.

Comment: Why not? Depends how you parse the expression in 2).

Comment: The standard is clear about how to parse both expressions. So no "depends". (Just for the sake of discussion: if a non-greedy approach was used, version 1 (`a+ ++b++`) would invoke UB. Either way, one of the expressions invokes UB. No compiler will alternate between greedy/non greedy atr random as your answer might imply).

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my reply!