# In C, is a+++b equal to a+b++?

Tags: c

In C, is a+++b equal to a+b++?

Comment: @StoryTeller It is just one increase operation and the varible is not used twice, I would figure it is not UB.

Comment: The 'maximal munch' rule covers this; one place it is described is [Why doesn't `a+++++b` work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work-in-c).

Comment: None of the code in the question as currently shown has undefined behaviour.  The requirements of the standard are clear.  The assignments could/should be written `c = a++ + b;` and `c = a + b++;`.  That is how the compiler will interpret them, thanks to the maximal munch rule.

Comment: Now the real question is, what does `++a+-+-+-+-+b++` mean? Lets ponder that for hours.

Comment: To answer the actual question, `a++ + b` and `a + b++` are indeed equal, if both `a` and `b` start with the same value; it's just that for the second line, the previous `a++` has incremented the starting value of `a`.

Answer (score 5):

They **are** and **will be** equal if you supply the **same** initial values of the operands.

In your case, the side effect of the first statement (post increment on `a`) is affecting the second one. Due to the presence of the post-increment in the first expression, `a` is incremented to `3` before the next statement is executed.

**Re-initialize** the variables with the same genesis value before calculating the second one.

Comment: I don't think the OP made that heavy a mistake. But we'll see.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sure sir, don't hesitate to update/correct me if I'm wrong, thank you. :)

Comment: To be honest I'm starting to doubt the OP since there is lack of confirmation. So have an UV.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) to understand it.

The confusing thing here is that `a+++b` may be read as either `a + (++b)` or as `(a++) + b`. According to the [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), it is actually looks like:

```
int a=2, b=3, c;

c = (a++) + b; // 2+3=5 and 'a' will be 3 after that line
printf("%d\n",c); // c = 5

c = a + (b++); // 3+3=6 and 'b' will be 4 after that line
printf("%d\n",c); // c= 6
```

From the link above:

`++` as sufix has highest priority.

`++` as prefix has lower priority.

`+` has even lower priority.

Comment: Nitpick: What operator precedence has to do with this?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - It matters when interpreting `+++`. How would you determine it's a post-increment on a and not a pre-increment on b?

Comment: @SouravGhosh `a+++b` could be read as `a+(++b)` or `(a++)+b`, each of it will give a different result.

Comment: @StoryTeller hmmm....interesting, you mind elaborating a little more? I'm sure i'm missing something there.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Well. The post-increment has a higher precedence than pre-increment and it associates with the expression on its left, so an expression like `+++` could have a clear meaning to the compiler, even without any spaces. For unary operators, the precedence is usually used to disambiguate such convoluted expressions.

Comment: @AlexLop. can you give me an example where `a+++b` is actually read as `a+(++b)`,? thanks.

Comment: @AlexLop. `a + ++b` will be parsed as `a + (++b)` and `a+++b` will be always parsed as `(a++)+b`. It does not depend on operator precedences, the distinction is due to the lexical analysis phase.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Please note Marian's comment.

Comment: @SouravGhosh According to C operator precedence, never. But this is well known to the compiler but only to few programmers. So unintentionally, a programmer may write a+++b meaning a + (++b) but the actual result will be (a++) + b.

Comment: @AlexLop. :) I know. The point I'm still unable to get is how that has _anything_ to do with the operator precedence.

Comment: @SouravGhosh OK, so maybe I misunderstood you. Did you mean why `(a++) + b` is not equal to `a + (b++)`? That is your question?

Comment: Expression parsing has nothing to do with operator precedence, which is a higher level concept. C11 6.4/4 determines how this expression is parsed. Therefore this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int a=2, b=3, c;

 c = (a++) + b; // The value for a will be 3 after that line
 printf("%d\n",c); // c = 5

 c = a + (b++); // So here a value is 3 (3+3) =6 after executing this line b value will be 4
  printf("%d\n",c); // c= 6
```

To avoid this you need to reinitialize the variables

Answer (score 0):

```
c = a+++b;
```

is equivalent

```
c = a++ + b;
```

`a++` means post-increment, means expression takes the value of `a` and then increment.

```
c = a+b++;
```

is equivalent

```
 c = a + b++;
```

`b++` means post-increment, means expression takes the value of `b` and then increment.

**If you provide same value in both cases, then both express variable c same.**