# Is this an correct C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,b;
    a = -3--3;
    b = -3--(-3);
    printf("a=%d b=%d", a,b);
}
```

This program is an assignment given to us to find output.
But it shows
`expression is not assignable`

However, my other classmates got the output.

```
a = 0, b = -6
```

I don't understand how because the program feels wrong to me.

Comment: A compiler can be used to tell you if a program is syntactically correct, and if not, what and where the problems are.

Comment: What compiler shows that error, where? [Edit] to explain how/where you compile and quote the message in full including the line/column numbers implicated.

Comment: Use some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: C tokenisation follows the [maximal munch rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch). The expression `a=-3--3;` is tokenized as `a`, `=`, `-`, `3`, `--`, `3`, `;` ... and the token `--` cannot be syntactically associated to either it's left or right token.

Comment: This was incorrectly closed. Should be closed as dupe to for example this fairly canonical "maximal munch" duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing its just an issue of spacing your operators:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,b;
    a = -3 - -3;
    b = -3 - -(-3);
    printf("a=%d b=%d", a,b);
}
```

This gives your desired output:

```
a = 0, b = -6
```

the `--` in your code is considered as a decrement operator instead of a negative sign