# C unary operators

Tags: c, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

I try to understand the grammar behind the unary operators in the C language. According to this version of the standard [link](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), in Section 6.5.3 Unary operators have the following syntax:

```
unary-expression:
  ...
  ++ unary-expression
  ...
```

This means that something like this is legal form a grammar point of view:
`a = ++++b`. However, the gcc compiler provides this error: `lvalue required as increment operand`.

I don't really understand why?

According to the standard, `++b` is equivalent to `(b += 1)`. This means that `a=++++b` should be expanded to `a=((b+=1)+=1)`. Why the compiler give the above error?

Comment: Sorry, I closed this question pre-maturely, it isn't actually a duplicate of the "maximal much rule" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work. Opened once again.

Comment: `++b` is the value of `b` after incrementing. It is not `b` itself. If `b=4` prior to the operation, `++++b` would be similar to `++5` which is also not possible, because `5` is a value, not a variable that could be modified.

Comment: In a nutshell, the grammar specifies the *syntax* that governs legal C programs. Your example is syntactically valid, but it is rejected by the compiler because of type issues (i.e. it violates the *semantic* specification of C, which is not captured in the formal grammar). Put differently, the formal grammar only specifies a *subset* of the rules that a program must adhere to.

Comment: It is an obvious mistake in **informative** part of the standard. It has no standardization power.

Comment: @0___________ All syntax, constraints and semantics of chapter 6 in the standard are normative. The OP is quoting 6.5.3 syntax. I think you might be confusing this for Annex A.

Comment: @0___________ Is that actually a mistake? A grammer defines the syntax of a language. It doesn't mean that there aren't more rules to follow to make a valid program.

Comment: `++ unary-expression` is definitely not right

Comment: @0___________ Yes it is, this is a verbatim from normative syntax is 6.5.3 and it is cited correctly. I really have no idea what you are on about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain this fully, it takes us pretty deep into language lawyer-land. I'll try to explain it step by step.

When the pre-processor parses the expression `++++b` it looks for the longest sequence of characters that will form a valid operator, the so-called "maximal munch rule". In this case that means that the code will get treated as if we had written `++ ++b` (rather than `++ + +b` or some such).

As you noticed from the formal syntax, the prefix ++ and -- can be combined with other unary expressions and so we get "right to left associativity", meaning `(++(++b)`. However, the C grammar only specifies that *syntax-wise* it is fine to combine multiple unary operators like this, but if it is valid code or not depends on the individual operators.

From there we will end up pondering something that formal C calls "lvalues", essentially a modifiable memory location, as opposed to temporary results of expressions. For example in case `a + b` of two variables, both `a` and `b` individually are objects and lvalues, but the result of the addition expression is not.

Lets look at a valid expression first. Had you written `++*ptr` then that would be valid C, because the two unary operators in this case specify the following:

C17 6.5.3.1, emphasis mine

> **Constraints**
> **The operand of the prefix increment or decrement operator** shall have atomic, qualified, or unqualified real or pointer type, and **shall be a modifiable lvalue**.

C17 6.5.3.2, emphasis mine

> **The unary `*` operator denotes indirection**. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue** designating the object.

So the prefix `++` expects a modifiable lvalue and the prefix `*` delivers that, so `++*ptr` is fine.

However, in case of `++++b`, the result of the first `++b` is *not* an lvalue. So by adding another `++` on top of the first, we violate the above quoted constraint, meaning that the code is invalid C.

So why isn't the result of `++b` a lvalue? 6.5.3.1 says the following:

> The value of the operand of the prefix `++` operator is incremented. The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. The expression `++E` is equivalent to `(E+=1)`.

Ok so we have to go dig up the rules of `+=` (compound) assignment operators...
We find the relevant explanation in C17 6.5.16, emphasis mine:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, **but is not an lvalue.**

The compiler must therefore present a diagnostic message due to the constraint violation. We didn't violate the syntax rules, but we violated the constraints. Both syntax and constraints are kind of "no exceptions allowed" if you wish to call the code a strictly conforming C program.

Comment: i think this is the best answer: simply because of 6.5.16 Assignment operators Semantics 3 which I missed. Thanks.

In other words, the stadard enforces the assignment expression not to be lvalue. I wonder why ... because again, from a formal point of view the grammar is correct and could produce valid object code.

Comment: @BogdanTanasa Mostly historical reasons I think, although sequencing might also be why. If it had been an lvalue then consider `(x = y) += x` and other such obscure use-cases that if they were allowed, someone would no doubt start using them, just for the heck of it.

Comment: *from a formal point of view the grammar is correct and could produce valid object code*, you have the syntactic level **AND** the semantic. A syntactically correct "text" may be not be semantically correct. Think of using a variable not declared or of a wrong type...

Answer (score 2):

In the C grammar, `++b` is not an lvalue, hence cannot be the operand of the `++` operator.

The concept of *lvalue* is defined in the C Standard as:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than `void`) that potentially designates an object; if an *lvalue* does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the *lvalue* used to designate the object.

There is no list of C expressions that are *lvalues*, but the C Standard does mention in many places some expressions that are lvalues and some that aren't. There is no mention regarding the application of prefix operators, but the assignment `b += 1` is explicitly not an lvalue per:

> **6.5.16 Assignment operators**
> [...]
> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, but is not an *lvalue*.

Note that the C++ grammar may differ to this regard.

Comment: That i suspected it is the case, but i cannot find it in the standard. Could you please point  to the exact text?

Comment: That being said, the expression ```a = ++++b``` should be legal ... or ?

Comment: @BogdanTanasa: good point: I skimmed through the latest C23 draft and there is no *official* list of lvalue constructions. I updated the answer.

Comment: `a = ++++b;` is not legal in C, but it might be in C++.

Comment: but the fact that is not legal in C it is in fact a mistake ... since the grammar allows it. ```++b```, when ```b=4``` is the value of ```b``` after increment and ```b``` itself after increment is not lvalue.

Comment: @BogdanTanasa no, why? The expression `++b` does not designate an object. And the fact that something might be legal purely based on the grammar, does not mean it is legal based on semantics

Comment: Let's put it the other way around. Is it possible to construct something that is legal so that:  


unary-expression:
  ...
  ++ unary-expression
  ...

expands to something like ++++ ?!

Comment: @BogdanTanasa as the result of `++<x>` is not an object, it will never be valid in C.

Comment: @BogdanTanasa `++*++ptr` might be valid C. It's not about the syntax, but the rules for each operator.

Comment: @BogdanTanasa you could get `p++++` by rule `unary-expression: postfix-expression` and `postfix-expression: postfix-expression ++` and `ptr++` is an object (`ptr` after increment) which is an lvalue.

Comment: @chqrlie that the grammar part of the standard is informative only.

Comment: @0___________ Again, no idea how you came up with that idea. I think you are confusing this for the grammar _summary_ Annex A which in itself isn't normative but summarizes parts of chapter 6 that are. It all boils down 5.1.1.3 diagnostics: "A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit **contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint**"

Comment: @Lundin OP is quoting this not normative part in his question :) and he is asking abut it

Comment: @0___________ No, he is citing the normative syntax in 6.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

The `++b` sub-expression produces a temporary value which does not have an addressable storage location. Attempting to apply the `++` on that expression fails because that operator needs a modifiable location. An expression like `++5` would fail with the same error message.

You have to think of it recursively and then it becomes evident:

```
(++(++b))
```

The value of `++b` would only be usable as an operand of an operator that doesn't need a modifiable storage location, say `+`:

```
a + (++b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int a=((b+=1)+=1);
```

also gives the error:

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

(almost identical wording)